# stripe payment not working as expected in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment, card

I am trying to use Stripe to charge a credit card, but I am getting an error. Here is the code I am using:

```
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout"
// import confirmPayment from 'stripe-element';
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import axios  from "axios";
const key="pk_test_51MOn0RSCoZWqhGLghNbZGJNElj6EoHYkt03rWcPYTUpa1EUlMas5Rd2RY8Ta70ubtXaFVmchCdlqOPaXhkpYAQcO00i4y02duY";
export const Pay = () => {
  const [stripeToken,setStripeToken]=useState(null);
  const onToken=(token)=>{
setStripeToken(token)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/checkout/payment", {
          tokenId: stripeToken,
          amount: 3000,
        }
        );
        console.log(res.data)
        
        console.log(res.status)
        console.log(res.data)
        } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    if (stripeToken) {
      makeRequest();
    }
  }, [stripeToken]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <StripeCheckout
          name="shop"
          image="text"
          billingAddress
          shippingAddress
          description="Your total is $2000"
          amount={20000}
          token={onToken}
          stripeKey={key}
 
        >
          <button className="btn btn-success">Pay</button>
        </StripeCheckout>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const stripe=require("stripe")(process.env.SECRET_KEY_PAY)
exports.stripePayment=async(req,res,next)=>{
let error,status;
try{
const customer=await stripe.customers.create({
    email:req.body.email,
    source:req.body.token,
    payment_method: ['card', 'ach_credit_transfer'],}
    )
  const charge=await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount:req.body.amount,
    currency:"inr",
    customer:customer.id,
    description:req.body.description,

  })
console.log("charge:",{charge});
status="success"
}catch(err){
console.log(err)
}

}
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried the following things to fix the error:

- I have checked the credit card number and expiration date to make sure they are correct.
- I have tried using a different credit card.
- I have tried clearing my browser's cache and cookies.

**What I am expecting:**

I am expecting the credit card to be charged successfully.

**What I am seeing:**

I am seeing the following error message:

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid string: {:"0"=>"card"}
    at Function.generate (F:\React\e-commerce site\Api\node_modules\stripe\cjs\Error.js:10:20)
    at res.toJSON.then.Error_js_1.StripeAPIError.message (F:\React\e-commerce site\Api\node_modules\stripe\cjs\RequestSender.js:105:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
```

Comment: Could you try  `payment_method: 'card'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass an array of strings to the `payment_method` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-payment_method) when creating your Customer. This parameter expects a string, more specifically the ID of an existing Payment Method object. As such, the API is thrown an invalid request error.

I'd recommend studying the API reference to ensure that your parameters are correct and that you're sending valid values.

Comment: error :No such PaymentMethod: 'card'

Comment: Did you read the API reference I linked for the parameter you're trying to use?